# Onelogin Drupal 7 module error onelogin_saml_password_tab_disabled

Tags: drupal-7, saml, onelogin

I have configured two instances of the Drupal Onelogin module d7oneloginsaml2v2.2.4.zip 
as detailed on the Onelogin help page
https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/201173604-Configuring-SAML-for-Drupal

This is on two fresh installs of Drupal 7 and both times I have got the error:

Notice: Use of undefined constant onelogin_saml_password_tab_disabled - assumed 'onelogin_saml_password_tab_disabled' in onelogin_saml_menu_alter() (line 81 of/etc/drupal7/all/modules/contrib/onelogin_saml/onelogin_saml.module).

Please note that this error does not appear to prevent the module doing authentication.

Any ideas why this error is appearing? Is there something that I need to configure prior to enabling the module?

I am not a programmer so this may be fairly obvious to developers.

Thanks

Paul C

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug, [already fixed](https://github.com/onelogin/drupal-saml/commit/8291442175af01a0f433df7547db7d41119c12c0) on the repository, but the patch is not yet included in any release. Maybe download the code directly from github repository: https://github.com/onelogin/drupal-saml

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the latest from Github and that error is resolved. All working fine as far as I can tell so far. Appreciate the quick help Sixto.

Comment: There is a new release that includes that fix: https://github.com/onelogin/drupal-saml/releases/tag/v2.2.5